# How to update a datatype for a common parameter in all procedures in selected Database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

Is there any chance to update datatype value in all procedures at a time in particular database for example i have procedures with credentials like

```
@password varchar(50),
@employeeEmail varchar(150)
```

and now i need to update '@password' like

```
@password varchar(100),
@employeeEmail varchar(150)
```

Comment: There's no *magic* way to do this - you'd have to (1) enumerate all stored procedures, (2) look at their source code and the parameters defined, and if necessary (3) update their stored source code to a new situation

Comment: there is a way i can get all procedures in one table then why cant i update the text in that procedures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this is a simple solution, find all procedures that contain the search string, loop through them and replace that string in the definition and run it. This is a very simplistic solution with no error checking or transactions but show what can be done

```
DECLARE @searchstr VARCHAR(50), @replacestr VARCHAR(50), @str VARCHAR(MAX), @name VARCHAR(40)
SET @searchstr = '@password varchar(50),'
SET @replacestr = '@password varchar(100),'

DECLARE test_cursor CURSOR READ_ONLY FOR 
SELECT name, object_definition(OBJECT_ID)
FROM sys.objects
WHERE object_definition(OBJECT_ID) LIKE '%' + @searchstr + '%'
and type = 'P'

OPEN test_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM test_cursor INTO @name, @str
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS <> -1)
BEGIN
    IF (@@FETCH_STATUS <> -2)
    BEGIN
        PRINT @name
        SET @str = REPLACE(@str, @searchstr, @replacestr)
        EXEC ('drop proc ' + @name)
        EXEC (@str)
    END
    FETCH NEXT FROM test_cursor INTO @name, @str
END

CLOSE test_cursor
DEALLOCATE test_cursor
```

Comment: In my database total 900 procedures are there will the cursor works

Comment: I don't think that should be a problem, just to be on the safe side make sure you make a backup or try this on a test database. To see if it works limit the number of procedures to replace with TOP keyword, like TOP 10 or so. This way you can do the update in chunks

Answer (score 0):

An attempt.....

The following will produce a script to alter all the target procedure only where

1 -  Procedure is not a System Stored Procedure (i.e name doesnt start with sp_).
2 -  Procedure has a Parameter called `@password`.

... Hoping that you have not got any User Defined Procedure Names starting with `sp_`.

Once the script is created have a very careful look, at the script. Backup your database, Once happy only then execute the script. Happy days.

```
 SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Table to hold names of all the user defined Procedures
CREATE TABLE #UD_Procedures (Proc_Num INT IDENTITY(1,1), Proc_Name NVARCHAR(128))
GO

-- Table to hold Definitions of all the user defined Procedures
CREATE TABLE #UD_Proc_Definitinos (Def NVARCHAR(MAX))
GO

-- Populate Procedure Names table
INSERT INTO #UD_Procedures
SELECT OBJECT_NAME([OBJECT_ID])
 FROM sys.all_parameters ap
WHERE EXISTS  (SELECT 1
               FROM sys.procedures p 
               WHERE LEFT(name, 3) <> 'sp_'
                 AND OBJECT_NAME(ap.[object_id]) = p.name)
AND ap.Name = '@password'
GO


    DECLARE @Proc_Name NVARCHAR(128);

WHILE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM #UD_Procedures)
 BEGIN


     SELECT TOP 1 @Proc_Name = Proc_Name 
     FROM #UD_Procedures 
     ORDER BY Proc_Num

     INSERT INTO #UD_Proc_Definitinos
     EXECUTE sp_helptext @Proc_Name

     INSERT INTO #UD_Proc_Definitinos
     VALUES ('GO', ' ', ' ')

     DELETE FROM #UD_Procedures WHERE Proc_Name = @Proc_Name
 END


UPDATE #UD_Proc_Definitinos
 SET Def =    REPLACE(
                REPLACE(
                  REPLACE(
                     Def
                        ,'CREATE PROCEDURE', 'ALTER PROCEDURE')
                          ,'CREATE PROC', 'ALTER PROCEDURE')
                            ,'@password varchar(50)', ' @password varchar(100) '
                          )

-- Now select "Result to text file" and execute the following 

SELECT * FROM #UD_Proc_Definitinos

-- Save the file and Copy paste into SSMS and execute,,, 
-- just be on safe side backup your DB before you do anything :)

--  DROP temp tables 

DROP TABLE #UD_Procedures
GO
DROP TABLE #UD_Proc_Definitinos
GO
```